# How to format JavaScript Date object to not let hours overflow?

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

Let us consider following example

```
const date = new Date(0);
date.setSeconds(60*60*24-1);
console.log(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

outputs

```
23:59:59
```

I am searching for elegant way to have

```
const date = new Date(0);
date.setSeconds(60*60*24+1);
console.log(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

output

```
24:00:01
```

instead of

```
00:00:01
```

by elegant I mean without implementing my own Date object... Maybe it would be possible to set a custom length of the day? Increase from 24h to 99h?

Comment: There is no "hour 24", the hours in a day go from 0 to 23.  Take a step back... What is it you're actually trying to accomplish here?  Do you just need to know the count of hours produced by a number of seconds?  You don't need a `Date` object for that, you can determine it with simple arithmetic.  It's not really clear to me what the goal is here.

Comment: @David—yes there is. Formatting of dates and times varies greatly, there is an option for both *Intl.DateTimeFormat* and *toLocale\** methods to set the hour cycle to 24, so that midnight is represented as 24, not the more common 12 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @RobG who understood my question. The hour cycle is what I needed, unfortunately according to the docs it is restricted to values `h11`, `h12`, `h23`, `h24` and I would need `h99` which is not available.

Eventually I had to make my own ugly solution as it appears such a use case was not predicted in the standard, so here it is

```js
function unfortunatelyWeHadToWriteIt(nbsec) {
  // compute numerical values
  const nbhours = Math.floor(nbsec/(60*60));
  const nbminutes = Math.floor((nbsec - nbhours*60*60)/60)
  const nbseconds = Math.floor(nbsec - nbhours*60*60 - nbminutes*60);
  // convert them to padded strings
  const hours = String(nbhours).padStart(2, '0');
  const minutes = String(nbminutes).padStart(2, '0');
  const seconds = String(nbseconds).padStart(2, '0');
  // format
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

so let's compare it to the Date formatting

```js
// 27 hours, 13 minutes and 6 seconds
const nbsec = 60*60*27+13*60+6;
```

what Date will give us

```js
const date = new Date(0);
date.setSeconds(nbsec);
console.log(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

outputs `03:13:06`, it overflows at value of 24 hours. Now let's apply the `unfortunatelyWeHadToWriteIt` function

```js
console.log(unfortunatelyWeHadToWriteIt(nbsec))
```

outputs `27:13:06` which does not overflow.

Just to give you guys some context, I am playing games and displaying the playtime. It is more convenient to show number of hours than number of days of gameplay...

Comment: The *Intl* object is intended to present formatting according to customary use as defined by languages, it is not intended to be used for specific formatting (though the *formatToParts* is a useful tool for doing that). I doubt there is any culture identifiable by language anywhere that uses a modern time system that goes beyond 24 hours. But I don't have encyclopaedic knowledge of all languages and formats. :-) Hence *toLocale\** methods aren't going to help if you want to go beyond 24. :-(

Comment: It seems that what you want are durations, which are part of the [*Temporal* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) ([Temporal.duration](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/duration.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hour cycle in the hour cycle option (*hc*) and the language parameter available in the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and [*toLocaleTimeString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), e.g.

```js
console.log(
  new Date(2020,7,1,0,5).toLocaleTimeString('en-CA-u-hc-h24')
);
```

Whether the hour cycle setting "works" or not seems to depend on the language chosen and how it's set, so maybe not that reliable. Test thoroughly in different implementations.